# Meaning of :. after a .jar file in a terminal command

Tags: java, eclipse, networking, terminal

I am using a command which allows me to use a class from a `.jar` file, but I am not really sure of the meaning of the whole command. I also wanted to test my programs from Eclipse, but without understanding fully it, it's difficult to customise the run configurations.

The command is the following:

```
java -classpath transport.jar:. transport.FileSender MGBNSender 4000 localhost 3000 transport.jar 0
```

I have a few questions:

1. What's the meaning of `:.` after the `.jar` library?

The class `transport.FileSender` basically allows me to test by class `MGBNSender`, but so far I have not manage to test it from Eclipse. Could you please help me how should I do it?

I have already imported the `.jar` file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` adds the current directory to the class-path. You need that if you have any compiled Java source files (e.g. classes) in your local tree (for example, when developing, you might have your Main, or some other, class in your current directory).

Comment: So `.` does not refer to the classes in `transport.jar` (e.g. `FileSender`)? It does not seem the case because if I separate `.` from `:` (i.e. `: . `) it does not work. What's the meaning of `:`?

Comment: `:` is the separator on *NIX systems (windows has `;`).

Comment: Do you have any idea of an equivalent command for testing my class `MGBNSender` from Eclipse (or IntelliJ)? I know I need somehow to modify the configurations of `MGBNSender`... note that the main function is in `FileSender`...

Comment: In eclipse, goto "Run > Run Configurations ...". Add `transport.jar` to the class path, and set "Main Class" to `transport.FileSender`. Then click the "Arguments" tab, and set "Program Arguments" to `MGBNSender 4000 localhost 3000 transport.jar 0`. Then click "Run" (in the lower right).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks, that seems to work, the only thing is that I am not able to refer to the file `transport.jar` (i.e. the file to send), which is within the `src` folder...is it possible to refer to it or should I change the folder where these files to send are?

Comment: You'll need to add it to your project's build-path. Add it to your project, right click on it and select "Build Path > Add to Build Path".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks! Finally I will have some auto-completion :)